# how to define a value in an object with previous values from the same object

Tags: javascript

I am coding an object. I want that the object contains the first name the last name and combined with this two values a full name. In the code below I tried to implement but only the object as such will logged into the console.

```
const user = {
    firstName(firstName) {
        return firstName; 
    }, 
    lastName(lastName) {
        return lastName;
    },
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

console.log(`${user.firstName("Andrew")} ${user.lastName("Tate")}`);
console.log(user.fullName);
```

Comment: Are you trying to define `firstName` and `lastName` as properties of the `user` object?  
You  have some methods (`firstName` and `lastName`) that look like properties, but aren't.  The only property you have is `fullName`, which is trying to use those methods like they are properties.

Comment: Yes, I want that they are properties of the user object. Why are they not?

Comment: A property of an object can't be both a value and a method at the same time.  The code in your question defines `user.firstName` to be a method.  This is a *data property*.  Another kind of property, *accessor properties* were added that allow you run dynamic code as if they were regular properties.  See [Property getters and setters](https://javascript.info/property-accessors)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this.firstName` and `this.lastName` don't exist.  I've modified your firstName and lastName methods to set those values:

```js
const user = {
    firstName(firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this.firstName;
    }, 
    lastName(lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this.lastName;
    },
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

console.log(`${user.firstName("Andrew")} ${user.lastName("Tate")}`);
console.log(user.fullName);
```

Comment: Fixes the coding issue, but not the design issue.  Neither the `firstName` nor `lastName` method are usable as getters.

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: Actually.  I was correct the first time.  See the second answer I posted which demonstrates that the `firstName` property cannot hold both a method and a value at the same time. In fact, without using the `get` keyword the method is not actually a property getter, it's just a method.

Answer (score 1):

Replaces the "property" methods with separate getters and setters for these properties, which are then used in the computed property `fullName`.  Note that you cannot use `this.firstName` to store the value of the property.  [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

> It is not possible to simultaneously have a setter on a property that holds an actual value.

```js
const user = {
    set firstName(firstName) {
        this.first_name = firstName; 
    }, 
    get firstName() {
        return this.first_name; 
    }, 
    set lastName(lastName) {
        this.last_name = lastName;
    },
    get lastName() {
        return this.last_name; 
    }, 
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

user.firstName = "Andrew"
user.lastName = "Tate"

console.log(user.fullName);
console.log(`user.first_name === user.firstName: ${user.first_name === user.firstName}`);
```

As shown at the end of the above snippet, the properties that hold the actual value of the first and last name are visible (and modifiable) from outside the object.  You can prevent this by using an IIFE to create a private namespace and store the values there:

```js
user = (function () {
  let private = {}
  const user = {
    set firstName(firstName) {
        private.firstName = firstName; 
    }, 
    get firstName() {
        return private.firstName; 
    }, 
    set lastName(lastName) {
        private.lastName= lastName;
    },
    get lastName() {
        return private.lastName; 
    }, 
    get fullName() {
        return `${private.firstName} ${private.lastName}`;
    }
  }
  return user
})()

user.firstName = "Andrew"
user.lastName = "Tate"

console.log(user.fullName);
console.log(user.firstName);
console.log(user.lastName);
console.log(user.private);
```

(Or just create User as a class and use private variables)

Comment: Why do I have to define them additionally with get or set?

Comment: `get` and `set` are keywords that lets the interpreter know that these are not actually methods, but rather getters and setters for a property.  This is why when you use what looks like a method to set the value (i.e `user.firstName = "Andrew") the method is not replaced by the string.  Rather the setter is called instead.

Answer (score 0):

Demonstration of why you need to use `get` and `set` in order to create dynamic properties.

```js
const user = {
    firstName(firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this.firstName;
    }, 
    lastName(lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this.lastName;
    },
    get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}

console.log(user.firstName) // this method defined above will literally be logged here.
user.firstName("Andrew")    // [Side Effect!] this uses the method to set the "first name", but the side effect is to actually replace the method with the string
console.log(user.firstName) // this will be "Andrew"
user.firstName()            // this will throw an error because "Andrew" is not a method.
console.log(user.firstName)
user.firstName = "Andrew"
console.log(user.firstName)
```